# pppoe в archlinux: интернет пропадает после обновления и перезагрузки

Tags: archlinux

Здравствуйте, у меня проблема с интернетом в archlinux. На ноутбуке интернет подключается через pppoe-setup. Затем после обновления системы и перезагрузки интернет пропадает и не подключается. Кто нибудь знает, как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала попробуйте следующее:

```
lsmod | grep rndis_hostmodprobe rndis_hostifconfig -a
```

([В помощь...](http://vektor-plus.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=44&Itemid=38) системы разные, но суть одна и та же.)

Comment: ((((не помогло ,в eth0 норм все, пингует роутер ,а вот ppp0 пакетов ноль..

Comment: внимательно изучите pppoeconf,я вам ссылку скинул,вы пробовали сделать  как там описанно?